# Google sheets custom function returning wrong time difference

Tags: javascript, date, google-sheets

I'm writing custom function for google sheets. 
One part should calculate delta of two difference times.

```
  function timeOut(input) {
    var difference = input[0][1]-input[0][0];
    var output = new Date(difference);

    return output;
  }
```

Variable **difference** contains zero. 
The problem is that new Date(0) is returning

> Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

which instead of

> Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

So difference of 9 hours minus 9 hours is 1 hours, which is obviously wrong.

Could you pinpoint me, what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`00:00:00 GMT+0100` would be -1 hour since it is +0100, the timezone matters, `01:00:00 GMT+0100` really is 0 hours.

If you want to get GMT, you can use `toGMTString()`:

```
var date = new Date(0);
alert(date.toGMTString()); // prints Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
```

Comment: Oh, I was thinking I've forgot something really stupid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually obviously correct, on the 00:00:00 of the GMT time, in +0100 the time was 01:00:00.

If you need the GMT time you can:

```
var GMTTime = new Date( -new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000 );
```